# In Full-screen prevent Dock to unhide when mouse hits bottom

Tags: dock, mouse, fullscreen

(using Mavericks 10.9.2 (latest))

Using an application in **Full-screen** (eg VirtualBox), is there a way **not** to have the **Dock** show when the **mouse** hits the bottom of the screen?

Tried

```
defaults write com.apple.dock autohide-delay -float 3
```

to increase the delay (3 seconds) the mouse has to stay at the bottom to get the Dock unhide. But it's been confirmed to have no effect in Mavericks (10.9.1, 10.9.2) *when in full-screen*.

(No option in VirtualBox either, this is a problem in any (most?) full-screen app anyway).

Comment: does adding the killall Dock help ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Nope. Did it along the other instructions to change the delay.

Comment: If you use the trackpad, you can lift your finger as soon as the cursor hits the bottom of the screen to prevent the dock from popping up. I don't know of an equivalent for the mouse, though.

Comment: @daGuy I'm using the trackpad, so the tip works... however that's not very convenient / practical. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm using this: defaults write com.apple.Dock tilesize -int 1 && killall -HUP Dock This will make the Dock very very small. Not a perfect solution but the best I found.